# Can I filter large lists with angular on client-side?

Tags: performance, angular5

I'm trying to find some information about the performance of angular.

If I had a list of 10k (or 50k) objects with 20 attributes each, would an average pc be able to filter this array in a reasonable time?

(Assuming a good implementation and this beeing the only operation executed)

Does anybody have any expierience in this direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, unless you can find a way to do this asynchronously; it's going to cause blocking UI issues.  I've found the average "PC" (and let's not forget browsers are not created equal) is too slow for my use cases and that was with more simple objects (less attributes).

If you had a very limited set of attributes you actually want to filter on, there is a chance you could speed up the work by leveraging IndexedDB.